# How to visualize the cluster result as a graph with different node color based on its cluster?

Tags: python, csv, graph, cluster-analysis, networkx

i  have a geodesic distance of graph data in .csv format

[image: data.csv]

i want to reduce it into 2D using Multidimensional Scaling (MDS) and cluster it using Kmedoids

This is my code:

```
# coding: utf-8
import numpy as np
import csv
from sklearn import manifold
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances
import kmedoidss

rawdata = csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'r').readlines()[1:])

# Process the data into a 2D array, omitting the header row
data, labels = [], []
for row in rawdata:
    labels.append(row[1])
    data.append([int(i) for i in row[1:]])
#print data

# Now run very basic MDS
# Documentation here: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.MDS.html#sklearn.manifold.MDS
mds = manifold.MDS(n_components=2, dissimilarity="precomputed")
pos = mds.fit_transform(data)

# distance matrix
D = pairwise_distances(pos, metric='euclidean')

# split into c clusters
M, C = kmedoidss.kMedoids(D, 3)

print ('Data awal : ')
for index, point_idx in enumerate(pos, 1):
    print(index, point_idx)

print ('\n medoids:' )
for point_idx in M:
    print('{} index ke - {} '.format (pos[point_idx], point_idx+1))

print('')
print('clustering result:')
for label in C:
    for point_idx in C[label]:
        print('cluster-  {}:{} index- {}'.format(label, pos[point_idx], point_idx+1))
```

kmedoidss.py

```
import numpy as np
import random

def kMedoids(D, k, tmax=100):
    # determine dimensions of distance matrix D
    m, n = D.shape

    # randomly initialize an array of k medoid indices
    M = np.sort(np.random.choice(n, k))

    # create a copy of the array of medoid indices
    Mnew = np.copy(M)

    # initialize a dictionary to represent clusters
    C = {}
    for t in xrange(tmax):
        # determine clusters, i. e. arrays of data indices
        J = np.argmin(D[:,M], axis=1)
        for kappa in range(k):
            C[kappa] = np.where(J==kappa)[0]
        # update cluster medoids
        for kappa in range(k):
            J = np.mean(D[np.ix_(C[kappa],C[kappa])],axis=1)
            j = np.argmin(J)
            Mnew[kappa] = C[kappa][j]
        np.sort(Mnew)
        # check for convergence
        if np.array_equal(M, Mnew):
            break
        M = np.copy(Mnew)
    else:
        # final update of cluster memberships
        J = np.argmin(D[:,M], axis=1)
        for kappa in range(k):
            C[kappa] = np.where(J==kappa)[0]

    # return results
    return M, C
```

how to visualize the cluster result as a graph with different node color based on its cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need MDS to run kMedoids - just run it on the original distance matrix (kMedoids can also be made to work on a similarity matrix by switching min for max).

Use MDS only for plotting.

The usual approach for visualization is to use a loop over clusters, and plot each cluster in a different color; or to use a color predicate. There are many examples in the scipy documentation.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html

> ```
> colors = np.array([x for x in 'bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk'])
> colors = np.hstack([colors] * 20)
> y_pred = labels.astype(np.int)
> plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], color=colors[y_pred].tolist(), s=10)
> ```

where `X` is your `pos` variable (2d mds result) and `labels` are an integer cluster number for every point. Since you don't have your data in thid "labels" layout, consider using a loop instead:

```
for label, pts in C.items():
    plt.scatter(pos[pts, 0], pos[pts, 1], color=colors[label])
plt.show()
```

Comment: it has error :( 
`y_pred = labels.astype(np.int) 
AttributeError : 'list' object has no attribute 'astype' `

Comment: The snippet is from the linked web page, this is not *your* labels list. You need to transform your cluster assignment into such a numpy array. `labels` is the usual name in python, and sklearn would return this. Since you have your own kmedoids, you need to modify it to produce this format.

Comment: which should i modify? i really confused

Comment: Look at the link. Or use the alternative i posted.